# ¿Actualizar tabla (bootstrap-table) automaticamente al pasar parametros de dos input?

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter

Como puedo hacer que mi tabla se actualice de manera automática tomando el valor de dos `input` en `JS`, utilizo `JSON`, ya puede pasar los parámetros a la consulta el problema es que mi tabla no se actualiza.

Este es algo de código que utilizo, investigando encontré que `Bootstrap Table` utiliza la propiedad `"refresh" {query: {foo: 'bar'}}`.

¿Como lo adaptaría a ello?

```
function actualizarTabla(datoFechaIni, datoFechaFin) {
  obtenerTablaAjax('venta', '<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/modulos/supervisor/supinicio/datos_ventas', {
    fechaIni: datoFechaIni,
    fechaFin: datoFechaFin
  }, '<?= base_url("assets/img/elems/loader.gif"); ?>');
}

function cargaInicial() {

  $("#e-fechaInicio").change(function() {
    actualizarTabla($("#e-fechaInicio").val(), $("#e-fechaFin").val());
  });
  $("#e-fechaFin").change(function() {
    actualizarTabla($("#e-fechaInicio").val(), $("#e-fechaFin").val());
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BootstrapTable es bastante sencillo de utilizar, bastaría

```
$('#venta').bootstrapTable("refresh", {
    url: "<?= base_url(); ?>index.php/modulos/supervisor/supinicio/datos_ventas",
    query: {
        fechaIni: datoFechaIni,
        fechaFin: datoFechaFin
    }
});
```

Como puedes observar, `bootstrapTable` toma como primer argumento una cadena, la cual indica el comando. El segundo argumento es un objeto con los datos necesarios como la URL de la petición y la `query` que requiere.